# I am sending an angularjs php id but it is not

Tags: angularjs

the problem is that I wrote a code that this code will send php to the select value alib and the data will be correct

http://jsfiddle.net/wUPdW/307/

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
 app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$http','$scope', function($scope ,$http){
  $scope.myMethod = function() {
alert($scope.myValue)    
$http.get('ajaxData.php?kateid=' + $scope.myValue).success(function (data) {

alert(data)    


    });
}
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controller function's injector parameters order have to match the annotation's injects order.

Change: `app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$http','$scope', function($scope ,$http){`
to: `app.controller('MyCtrl', [$scope', '$http', function($scope ,$http){`

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/hkgb91zm/18/)

Comment: Thank you. now i am not getting any data from php